# characterization of normed space(L2)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

if $\left\|\frac{f_n(x)}{x-i}\right\|_{2}=\displaystyle\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{f_n(x)}{x-i}\right|^2d\mu(x)\right)^\frac{1}{2} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $f_n(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, $i$ a complex number and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. How can i justify that $\left\|f_n(x)\right\|_{2} \rightarrow 0$ also?

I have been trying to use the Holders inequality but I am getting the whole thing messed up. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by $f_n(x)\in\mathbb C[x]$, exactly? Just that $f_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ or any additional assumption?

Comment: $f_n(x)$ is just any polynomial of degree n.we could use $f$ instead

Comment: You don't say if  $\mu\geq 0$.  If not, the integral could be negative and its square root complex.  So let's assume $\mu\geq 0$.  
If $\mu$ has compact support in $\mathbb{R}$ then $|1/(x-i)|^2$ is bounded from below there, so $\|f_n\|_2\leq C\|f_n/(x-i)\|_2$ and so we have what you want.  I can't say what happens if $\mu$ lacks compact support but goes to zero so quickly at $\pm\infty$ that $\|f_n\|_2<\infty$ for some nonzero real polynomials $f_n$.